# Can you use the force of gravity (ie. surface of Earth = 9.8m/s^2) to calculate gravitational time dilation?

Tags: gravity

I am having trouble tying the Schwarzschild radius to gravitational force as I believe it is not fixed when considering different masses.

I am getting results that show a different time dilation for the same gravitational force (different radiuses for different masses).

What I mean is, the gravitational time dilation I am experiencing at the surface of the Earth is different that around the Sun at a radius that would give the same gravitational force as the Earth at its surface.

Does this make sense that I would be getting these results?

Comment: Combining Newtonian gravity with general relativity generally doesn't work.

Comment: Yes results make sense.